# View [emails.password] not found in Laravel 5 / Angular project.

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add a password reset mechanism to my Laravel 5.0 / AngularJS app. I'm at the step when I need to send an email with a reset link, and am running into the error: `View [emails.password] not found.`

Since I am using Angular on the front end, I changed my default view path in `config/view.php` to:

`'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('public/app')),
],`

When I call `sendResetLink()` it throws an exception saying: `View [emails.password] not found.` The stack trace specifically mentions that it cannot find this view in `public/app` of my project.

I did a bit of research and found out that emails.password corresponds to a blade view located here: `laravel/resources/views/emails/password.blade.php`

I also know that this view corresponds to the email body.

For some reason, my Laravel project does not have this file so I created it in the `public/app` directory of my project.

The file that I created is called password.blade.php and has the following code in it:

`Click here to reset your password: {{ url('password/reset/'.$token) }}`

I'm a newbie with Laravel and don't really know how to register blade views, or even how the view `'emails.password'` maps to password.blade.php.

What can I do to resolve this issue? Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put that blade file in the directory that Laravel expects it. `view('emails.password') in Laravel` refers to the `password.blade.php` file in `resources/views/emails/`. For example if you wanted to display the view of "profile" `profile.blade.php` in the users directory `resources/views/users/`, you would use `view('users.profile')`

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding a folder: `app/public/emails` and adding `password.blade.php` to it. So the first word corresponds to the folder, and the second word corresponds to the name of the blade file? Could you recommend any documentation that explains this better?